# Is this #define equivalent to this variable definition in C?

Tags: c, microchip, microprocessors

Consider this `#define`:

```
#define msd_buffer              ((volatile char *) MSD_BUFFER_ADDRESS)
```

and this variable definition:

```
volatile char *msd_buffer = MSD_BUFFER_ADDRESS;
```

Are the two definitions of `msd_buffer` — as variable and as macro — equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `#define` is a macro. It acts as a direct copy-pasta of what you pass into it. So, `msd_buffer` is not a variable, it is a cast to a volatile char array.

Assuming example usage like this:

```
msd_buffer[160] = 0xFF;
```

It would be the same as using it as a variable. However, it doesn't have all the features of a variable, such as assignment:

```
msd_buffer = NEW_BUFFER_ADDRESS; // invalid!
```

Or address taking:

```
my_func(&msd_buffer); // invalid!
```

If you understand these drawbacks (and perhaps there are more), then you are on your way to using a macro like this.

Answer (score 1):

A define statement is just a textual substitution. Nothing more. So in your case, not really.